# Memory layout of a C++ Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

In trying to better understand the implementation of C++ lambdas, I fooled the compiler into treating a lambda as an object, and it seems that they are laid-out the same way in memory.

**Note**: This is just for clarification, I'm not advocating writing these kinds of hacks in production

Is this guaranteed by the language spec, or a compiler implementation detail?

```
struct F
{
    int a;  int b;  int c;
    void printLambdaMembers()
    {
        cout << this << endl; // presumably the lambda 'this'
        cout << a << endl; // prints 5   
        cout << b << endl;
        cout << c << endl;
    }
};

void demo()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    int c = 7;
    auto lambda = [a,b,c]() { cout << "In lambda!\n";  };
    // hard cast the object member function pointer to the lambda function 
    void(decltype(lambda)::*pf)() const = (void(decltype(lambda)::*)() const) (&F::printLambdaMembers);
    // run the member function on the lambda pointer
    (lambda.*pf)();  // we get 5,6,7

}
```

Comment: _" I fooled the compiler into treating a lambda as an object"_ This is funny because lambda are objects of anonymous type, **by definition** :)

Comment: Is it really so hard to check the Standard that we need a question paraphrasing it for every possible detail?

Comment: @YSC a slightly more pedantic way of stating that would be "I fooled the compiler into treating a lambda as an object *of some unrelated class type*", by violating strict aliasing, with the associated symptoms of UB. You can (probably) do similar things with `int[3]` objects

Comment: @Caleth less funny though.

Comment: @YSC Great, now I can't edit my question, as it would invalidate all these comments.

Comment: @GonenI Yes you can. Improvements of the question / answers have precedence over the relevance of their comments. Edit your question, and flag the comments as obsolete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard does not require lambda closures to have a particular layout. See [`[expr.prim.lambda.closure]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure):

> The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the closure type, whose properties are described below.
>
> ...
>
> The closure type is not an aggregate type. **An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below** provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:
>
> - the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable, or
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class.
>
> An implementation shall not add members of rvalue reference type to the closure type.

---

However, to conform to the platform ABI and to have object files interoperable, the compilers probably have to layout and name mangle lambda objects in absolutely the same way.

Answer (score 4):

This is entirely implementation-defined.
However, since lambdas are just instances of classes, it makes sense that they'd be generated by the compiler to look like any other class.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation specific.

Moreover, in your case, capture of lambda are not used, so might even be elided...